# Cgridview In Parentview

Tags: php, gridview, yii

Yii 1.1.14

I have an employee table and a comment table
In the employee view i want to show all the comments of the employee in a grid (after the employee fields)
I tried to follow the example [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/323/dynamic-parent-and-child-cgridview-on-single-view-using-ajax-to-update-child-gridview-via-controller-after-row-in-parent-gridview-was-clicked)

Here is where I am :

New code to defining a new search function in the model :

```
public $commentdate_param;
public $commentobservation_param;
...
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('public $commentdate_param, commentobservation_param, ...', 'safe', 'on'=>'search, searchIncludingComments'),
);
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'employeecomments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Employeecomments', 'employee_id'),
    );
}
public function searchIncludingComments($parentID)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with=array('employeecomments');
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->compare('t.employee_id',$parentID,false); 
        $criteria->compare('employeecomments.date', $this->commentdate_param,true);
        $criteria->compare('employeecomments.observation', $this->commentobservation_param,true);
        $sort = new CSort;
        $sort->attributes = array(
            'commentdate_param' => array(
            'asc' => 'date_desc',
            'desc' => 'date_desc DESC',
            ), '*', /* Treat all other columns normally */
        );
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>$sort,
        ));
    }
```

Adding code in the controller actionView :

```
...
$child_model = new Employee("searchIncludingComments");
$child_model->unsetAttributes();
$this->render('view',array(
    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    'child_model'=>$child_model,
    'parentID' => $id
));
```

Adding code in the view :

```
...
<h3>Comments</h3>
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'child-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$child_model->searchIncludingComments($parentID),
    'filter'=>$child_model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'date',
        'observation',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
...
```

But I must have missed something because when it comes to grid rendering stops - but no error in log
Would be nice if somebody could help me !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me - all my changes and controler are worthless because now I do all stuff in the view :

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'comments-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>new CActiveDataProvider('Employeecomment',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'employee_id=:eid',
                'params'=>array(':eid'=>$model->id),
            ),
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'date DESC',
            ),
        )),
```

Sure there is something I did not understand why it did not work ...